# .NET Core Azure WebJob Trace Logs only logs 1 entry

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a .NET Core WebJob deployed and I setup logging onto Azure Storage. On the App Service works great, but on this WebJob it doesn't. Actually on other web jobs it works great, but those are not .NET Core. So the problem is that it logs only 1 entry, after that nothing. On the WebJob dashboard it shows all of the trace. I'm out of ideas. Here is how I setup (which apart from settings, is exactly how it's setup on the AppService.

**Update:**
I created this utility class:

```
public class LogUtil
{
    public LogUtil()
    {
    }
    private static bool loggerSet;
    private static ILogger<Program> logger;
    public static ILogger<Program> Logger
    {
        get
        {
            if (LogUtil.loggerSet) return LogUtil.logger;
            LogUtil.loggerSet = true;

            AzureAppServicesDiagnosticsSettings settings = new AzureAppServicesDiagnosticsSettings
            {
                BlobName = "trace.txt",
                FileSizeLimit = int.MaxValue,
                BlobCommitPeriod = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,500)
            };

            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
            .AddConsole()
            .AddDebug()
            .AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics(settings);

            LogUtil.logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
            return LogUtil.logger;
        }
    }
}
```

And it's called like the following:

```
    //...
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LogUtil.Logger.LogInformation("WebJob begins...");

        LogUtil.Logger.LogInformation("this line gets logged sometimes");

        LogUtil.Logger.LogInformation("this line does not get logged");
        //...
    }
```

So the 2nd call is never logged.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am thinking that I am missing something.

Comment: Can you provide a sample WebJob that shows how you are logging? That could be a factor as I have seen this behavior if you call an `async` with an `await` but you have your method return `void` instead of `async Task`. That may not be your specific problem but more sample code could help us help you.

Comment: @Jaxidian, just added the utility class and the 1st 2 calls to the log. I've actually tried without making ILogger generic...just to rule that out, but nothing.

Comment: I have checked this issue and found that .NET Core Azure WebJob could not trace any logs in Azure Blob Storage, while the webjob dashboard could see all logs. Could you provide some core code within `Program.SetupConfig();`?

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT I added SetupConfig. The logging works on the first call, but after that it only displays on the web job dashboard. I even removed AddConsole() and AddDebug() to see if that did anything (just in case, I wasn't sure if those are labeled with [Conditional("DEBUG")]. so perhaps I just need to manually create my own logs? It's no problem, just I wanted to have something already created, or perhaps I can find something in another library. If that's the case, if you write that up in an answer I can mark it.

Comment: I have rechecked this issue and I could reproduce the same result. After some trials, I tried to modify `AzureAppServicesDiagnosticsSettings` setting but without luck. Then I found if I invoke `Console.ReadLine()` or `Thread.Sleep` to stop or wait for a while before the program exit, then I could retrieve the whole logs from blob (file), until now I did not find the cause. I searched the related resources, since your are using NetCore, a lot of solutions are useless. I assumed that you could try to implement the logging by yourself.

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT the crazy thing is that I finally got it working after a few tries, but I had to make another change and I noticed after viewing the log, but I didn't commit every change/publish. I have to retrace my steps to see how I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the code to reflect my final deployed code that works. I am assuming that my tests did not log everything, because it was so short. This might be some strange factor. I'm not sure if removing a setting for BlobCommitPeriod would make a difference, but as we are live with this and I need the logs...it's going to stay there until we can test on a stage environment what options are needed or not. So basically it works when the web job runs completely, which can take 10-20 minutes. When I ran tests, it only logged 1 or 2 lines, but that was very short running period. literally 2-5 seconds long. So hopefully that is not an issue with anyone having this problem, but for me works. I just need the full log when it does the full running, if it's called and it's not needed, then we'll know by another log that is in place. I hope this helps someone.